# Ubuntu v20 does not detect systemd-boot as installed

Tags: apt, systemd, bootloader

[Running Ubuntu v20.04 in VMware VM)

All of my systems run **systemd-boot**, with all related grub packages/files purged. When I ran today's update, there was a new kernel (v5.4.0-66). However, I canceled the transaction because my system was trying to (re)install **grub**. After adding this to `/etc/apt/preferences.d`:

```
$ cat nogrub.pref
# To prevent repository packages from triggering the installation of GRUB

Package: grub*
Pin: release a=*
Pin-Priority: -10
```

I reran the update, but now I got prompted to install **lilo**. So I then added a second pref file to `/etc/apt/preferences.d` to block **lilo** - finally the update proceeded as expected.

Is this normal behavior for Ubuntu? I saw the exact same thing in my Mint 20 system. Should I be doing something else to prevent these other bootloaders from trying to reinstall themselves? Why isn't Ubuntu detecting that a bootloader is already installed?

Answer (score 0):

I would go with it does not have a clue it is installed. If my attempt to find it is anything to go by.

```
root@zeus-H370M:/home/zeus# apt show systemd-boot
N: Unable to locate package systemd-boot
N: Unable to locate package systemd-boot
E: No packages found
root@zeus-H370M:/home/zeus# apt show grub
Package: grub
State: not a real package (virtual)
N: Can't select candidate version from package grub as it has no candidate
N: Can't select versions from package 'grub' as it is purely virtual
N: No packages found
root@zeus-H370M:/home/zeus# apt show grub-pc
Package: grub-pc
Version: 2.04-1ubuntu26.9
Priority: optional
Section: admin
Source: grub2
Origin: Ubuntu
```

Without those type of details of how it was installed, is there a conflicts line with `grub` and `lilo` mentioned so it prevents them from getting installed. Those are what you need to look for to sort this out. Almost missed this related package, though from the description it is not clear if it supplies the command or not and a file search now I think of that one too.

```
root@zeus-H370M:/home/zeus# apt-cache search systemd-boot
sicherboot - systemd-boot integration with UEFI secure boot support
systemd-bootchart - boot performance graphing tool
```

Nope no luck there either, unless this is what you use `/usr/lib/systemd/boot/efi/systemd-bootx64.efi`.

```
root@zeus-H370M:/home/zeus# apt-file search systemd-boot
manpages-de: /usr/share/man/de/man7/systemd-boot.7.gz
manpages-de: /usr/share/man/de/man8/systemd-boot-check-no-failures.service.8.gz
systemd: /lib/systemd/system/sysinit.target.wants/systemd-boot-system-token.service
systemd: /lib/systemd/system/systemd-boot-check-no-failures.service
systemd: /lib/systemd/system/systemd-boot-system-token.service
systemd: /lib/systemd/systemd-boot-check-no-failures
systemd: /usr/lib/systemd/boot/efi/systemd-bootx64.efi
systemd: /usr/share/man/man7/systemd-boot.7.gz
systemd: /usr/share/man/man8/systemd-boot-check-no-failures.8.gz
systemd: /usr/share/man/man8/systemd-boot-check-no-failures.service.8.gz
systemd: /usr/share/man/man8/systemd-boot-system-token.service.8.gz
systemd-bootchart: /lib/systemd/system/systemd-bootchart.service
systemd-bootchart: /lib/systemd/systemd-bootchart
systemd-bootchart: /usr/share/doc/systemd-bootchart/README
systemd-bootchart: /usr/share/doc/systemd-bootchart/changelog.Debian.gz
systemd-bootchart: /usr/share/doc/systemd-bootchart/copyright
systemd-bootchart: /usr/share/man/man1/systemd-bootchart.1.gz
```

So I still go with my initial conclusion, not a clue it is installed.

This was too long for comment and really should be here anyways. I just did an `EFI` entry for my machine I show all the commands on with the `efiboormgr` this is why I pointed to that .efi file suspecting you were doing such a thing, loading from `efi` only. That is not known to the packaging system it has no idea of changes you make to the system unless you tell it. You can do a fake .deb package that does nothing but install itself and has a conflicts line with `grub` and `lilo` then those never get installed or as you have done now apparently pin them so low they never get installed when a kernel is updated. Then you do whatever process you need to do to update that `efi` loading of the new kernel. There is your reason for the actions it took with your install.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Systemd-boot is part of **systemd**, so it's not installed separately. It does, obviously, need to be configured first; this is done by the `bootctl` command. Since this installs files into the EFI partition, it *should* be able to see them there.

Comment: added additional information.